# Start ipsec tunnel from another machine

Tags: ssh, ipsec

I have to monitor the IPsec tunnel on machine A which is behind a firewall F, where the OpenSwan sits on.

From machine A, if the tunnel goes down, I would restart the tunnel on machine F.
What I did on machine A is:

```
ssh  -t guest@firewall 'sudo /etc/init.d/ipsec restart'
```

I put `guest` user into `sudoers` with right permissions to execute `ipsec`.

The problem is that the tunnel does not restart and what I see on firewall F by doing

```
wath /etc/init.d/ipsec
```

is

```
IPsec stopped
but...
has subsystem lock (/var/lock/subsys/ipsec)!
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways

1) Forget `ssh` and add `dpdaction=restart` to your `ipsec.conf` on firewall F

2) If you wanna be sure that tunnel is up do this

```
ssh  -t guest@firewall 'sudo nohup /etc/init.d/ipsec restart'
```